# Output of Pytorch's view

Tags: view, pytorch

**Intuition:**

In Pytorch **view** reshapes the tensor and if there is a -1 parameter like this:
`x.view(2, -1)` then number of columns are left for the Pytorch to be decided..

**Question:**

I have came across this code:

`x.view(N, C, -1)` (where x's shape is  N, C, H, W)

What will be the shape of output tensor?

Comment: It will be `(N, C, H*W)`.

Comment: For each channel there will be H*W, right?

Comment: @Berriel Could you please share the logic behind this, I mean how is -1 indicating H*W?

Comment: You said that the original shape is (**N, C**, H, W), and the view is (**N, C**, -1). Note that N, C remain the same, therefore -1 will aggregate the remaining dimensions H **and** W, which results in H*W.

Comment: So, for example, if N=10, C=3 , H/W=24 then before it was: [10, 3, 24, 24] and now it would be: [10, 3, 576]. That is, all the rows will be concatenated together. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.